# Live web server migration

Tags: domain-name-system, migration

I need to replace an aging webserver which runs a busy website. I have the new hardware up and running, all software is installed. There's only one problem left where I'm looking for a solution:

When I change the A record for the
   domain in DNS, it takes a while for
   the change to propagate through the
   internet due to DNS caching. During that
   time, some users will hit the new
   server, and some will hit the old
   one, leading to data inconsistencies because there are now two databases.
   How can I switch everyone over
   instantly? I do not run the DNS server and cannot change anything but the A and CNAME records, but I could setup my own if that helps.

I can probably have an hour or two of downtime when moving overnight.

Thanks, Simon

**edit**: Thank you for all your answers. I'm accepting SmallClanger's answer because it's a viable solution, and I'm upvoting Brian because his answer gave me a new idea: Follow SmallClanger's solution up to the database migration, and then replace the old apache with an HTTP proxy which proxies all requests to the new server. I'd configure the proxy to address the new server by IP address, and it does not involve a temporary subdomain which might (despite the 302 code) end up in some bookmark directory, social network or browser cache.

Comment: the way the questions is formulated suggests that the old and the new server are not 'side-by-side' - but for clarification: you really need to switch DNS entries rather than re-assigning the old server's IP address to the new one?

Comment: These are two dedicated servers with two different providers, so no, they are not side-by-side and I cannot take IP addresses with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem you have is of maintaining database consistency during the switch. To have *zero* downtime, you'll have no choice but to set the two servers up in an active/active cluster. (even assuming, for the moment, that the cluster setup would involve no downtime itself, which is a bit of a stretch.).

Given that you can't change the TTL, you best step is to *minimise* downtime:

- Set the new site up on a second domain name (eg: `www2.example.com`), but make it answer to `www.example.com`, too. Point the DNS for `www2` at the new server only.
- Have the site files replicated and locked down from edits on both sides.
- Then in an advertised maintenance window, replace the live site with a 'down for upgrades' notice.
- Sync or copy the database across as required, and then start the new server.
- Then (and only then) make your DNS changes to the `www` record.
- Replace the old site config with a simple 302 redirect to `www2.example.com`
- Wait for the full TTL to expire (and then a bit) before taking the old server down.

This will make sure all traffic goes to the new site during the DNS propagation,  regardless of which server they go to initially, though it assumes your site is capable of being served from multiple domain names at the same time.

For a single-server LAMP stack (if that's what you've got), then this is your route to minimal (but not zero) downtime.

Answer (score 3):

You could configure the old web server to redirect all requests to the new IP. This can be done with mod_rewrite in apache.

Answer (score 0):

You could lower the TTL of your zone one or two days before the migration to a small value. After you've changed the A resource record you can raise the TTL again to its old value.

Answer (score 0):

You  have to  migrate  first   all data files on the new server (apache and mysql files)  . After that  when  you have 2   houres to stop server     you can synchronize all datafiles  with rsync.
LIke that  rsync  -avz  /var/www/sites (old-server)   user@hosts2:/var/www/sites  (new-servers)    . And  export import all datafiles on sql server from server 1 to new server . Then swich server 2

and stop old server   if  you have some problem start again server 1  and repear  errors on newserver .

But before  you start new server check for  errors  make own test.

Answer (score 0):

lower the TTL, and put up under maintance sign on old page?

Answer (score 0):

I thing  TTL is bad idea. Becouse  if  old server is alive  , some user  meybe will connect on  old server and another users meybe will use new server. If  you really have 2 hours    use syn and export inport all from sql to sql then swich on new server Am sure all will be  fine with mu solutions

Answer (score 0):

You could use the old server IP for your new server.